# install.packages() in R on GNU/Linux system

Tags: c++, r, linux, package, gnu

I install R (v. 4.2.2) in GNU Guix Linux-libre. But, after trying installation package 'Rcpp', I got error: std::__throw_bad_array_new_length().

```
> install.packages("Rcpp")
Installing package into ‘/home/guix/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/Rcpp_1.0.10.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2936173 bytes (2.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.8 MB

* installing *source* package ‘Rcpp’ ...
** package ‘Rcpp’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++14 -I"/gnu/store/kjd4gfz8frchb8n4ada2l6nssa9pnin6-r-minimal-4.2.2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include/  -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c api.cpp -o api.o
In file included from /gnu/store/fyc3x8nd2ln090y4ng020rvspwl5pc78-gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /home/guix/.guix-profile/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /home/guix/.guix-profile/include/c++/unordered_map:40,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:153,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:62,
                 from ../inst/include/RcppCommon.h:30,
                 from ../inst/include/Rcpp.h:27,
                 from api.cpp:26:
/home/guix/.guix-profile/include/c++/bits/new_allocator.h: In member function ‘_Tp* std::__new_allocator<_Tp>::allocate(size_type, const void*)’:
/home/guix/.guix-profile/include/c++/bits/new_allocator.h:125:20: error: ‘__throw_bad_array_new_length’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘bad_array_new_length’?
  125 |               std::__throw_bad_array_new_length();
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    bad_array_new_length
make: *** [/gnu/store/kjd4gfz8frchb8n4ada2l6nssa9pnin6-r-minimal-4.2.2/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:178: api.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rcpp’
* removing ‘/home/guix/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/4.2/Rcpp’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmptAJQ9x/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("Rcpp") :
  installation of package ‘Rcpp’ had non-zero exit status
```

The same error was after trying to install 'ggplot2'.

```
* installing *source* package ‘farver’ ...
** package ‘farver’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/gnu/store/kjd4gfz8frchb8n4ada2l6nssa9pnin6-r-minimal-4.2.2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c ColorSpace.cpp -o ColorSpace.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/gnu/store/kjd4gfz8frchb8n4ada2l6nssa9pnin6-r-minimal-4.2.2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c Comparison.cpp -o Comparison.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/gnu/store/kjd4gfz8frchb8n4ada2l6nssa9pnin6-r-minimal-4.2.2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c Conversion.cpp -o Conversion.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/gnu/store/kjd4gfz8frchb8n4ada2l6nssa9pnin6-r-minimal-4.2.2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c encode.cpp -o encode.o
In file included from /gnu/store/fyc3x8nd2ln090y4ng020rvspwl5pc78-gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h:33,
                 from /home/guix/.guix-profile/include/c++/bits/allocator.h:46,
                 from /home/guix/.guix-profile/include/c++/unordered_map:40,
                 from encode.h:4,
                 from encode.cpp:1:
/home/guix/.guix-profile/include/c++/bits/new_allocator.h: In member function ‘_Tp* std::__new_allocator<_Tp>::allocate(size_type, const void*)’:
/home/guix/.guix-profile/include/c++/bits/new_allocator.h:125:20: error: ‘__throw_bad_array_new_length’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘bad_array_new_length’?
  125 |               std::__throw_bad_array_new_length();
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                    bad_array_new_length
make: *** [/gnu/store/kjd4gfz8frchb8n4ada2l6nssa9pnin6-r-minimal-4.2.2/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:178: encode.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘farver’
* removing ‘/home/guix/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/4.2/farver’
```

I think that is need to install package in GNU/Linux system that is essential for R, but I don't know what. This is my system:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Guix System

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /gnu/store/xghpgl3fnr603z16vg7hldmpxygriqm2-openblas-0.3.20/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf8       LC_NUMERIC=C             
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.utf8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.utf8       LC_NAME=C                
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              LC_TELEPHONE=C           
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C      

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.2 tools_4.2.2    tcltk_4.2.2
```

Comment: I don't know the underbelly of modern GCC, but preprocessor is happily reading headers from `/home/guix/.guix-profile/include/c++/bits/` and then suddenly pulling them from `/gnu/store/fyc3x8nd2ln090y4ng020rvspwl5pc78-gcc-12.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bits/`. Not sure how kosher that is.

Comment: I’m not a Guix user but a NixOS user doing R things, which is similar (I think). These distributions work very differently than a “regular” Linux distro. But it looks like someone might have an r package to help install packages in Guix: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/guix.install/guix.install.pdf

Comment: Thank you, bs93! The command guix.install is very helpful!